# Get printer status with SNMP using Pysnmp

Tags: python, snmp, zebra-printers

I try to get status from my printer using SNMP protocol
The problem is, I've never used the SNMP and I have trouble understanding how can I get my status like ( PAPER OUT, RIBBON OUT, etc... ).

I configured my printer to enable the SNMP protocol using the community name "public"
I presume SNMP messages are sent on the port 161

I'm using Pysnmp because I want to integrate the python script in my program to listen to my printer and display status if there is a problem with the printer.

For now I've tried this code :

```
import socket
import random
from struct import pack, unpack
from datetime import datetime as dt
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
from pysnmp.proto.rfc1902 import Integer, IpAddress, OctetString


ip = '172.20.0.229'
community = 'public'
value = (1,3,6,1,2,1,25,3,5,1,2)

generator = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
comm_data = cmdgen.CommunityData('server', community, 1)  # 1 means version SNMP v2c
transport = cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161))

real_fun = getattr(generator, 'getCmd')
res = (errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds) \
    = real_fun(comm_data, transport, value)

if not errorIndication is None or errorStatus is True:
    print "Error: %s %s %s %s" % res
else:
    print "%s" % varBinds
```

The IP address is the IP of my printer
The problem is the OID: I don't know what to put in the OID field because I have trouble understanding how does OID work.

I found this page but I'm not sure it fits with all printers ==> [click here](https://secure.n-able.com/webhelp/NC_7-2-0_Cust_en/Content/N-central/Services/Services_PrinterStatus.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need your printer specific MIB file in common case. E.g., printer in my office seems to be not support both oids by your link. Also you can use `snmpwalk` to get available oids and values on your printer and if you somehow understand which values you need, you can use it for specific instance of your printer.

Comment: OK so snmpwalk can list OID from my printer ?

Comment: Yes, but without MIB file you can only guess of oid meaning.